# how to use cookies to store the watched time of a video in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I store in a cookie the watched time of a video when the user leaves the tab, or reload it? I've seen a code with jwplayer but I don't use this script and I wanted to know how to do something like that.

Here is an example with jwplayer.
https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/web-player-demos/resume-playback-with-cookies/

How can I do this however using a normal javascript? And not the jwplayer

Comment: Your problem can be split in four parts:
1. Detecting when the user switches to another tab
2. Detecting when the user leaves the page (document.addEventListener('unload', ...))
3. Getting the current video position
4. Saving a cookie

Comment: Yes, you're right, but how can i solve all these problems?

Comment: For 3., you can get your video element (e. g. with `getElementById`; I suppose you know how that works) and use its `currentTime` attribute.

Comment: For 4., you can use the object `document.cookie`. I do not know anything about that (as well as leaving tabs), but you can read e. g. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_cookie.asp

Comment: Yes I made it. should look something like: `document.getElementbyId(" video ").currentTime`